# AbstractAjaxTimerBehaviour prevents session expiration

Tags: wicket

I have a page on my application which has an AbstractAjaxTimerBehaviour with a duration of 2 minutes. My application session expire time is 30 minutes (configured in web.xml file). However, my session cannot get expired because this behaviour keeps it alive. What could I do to fix this problem?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You could do some magic and in the `AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior` and try some things in the `HttpSession` with [`setMaxInactiveInterval()`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setMaxInactiveInterval(int)) and [`getLastAccessedTime()`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getLastAccessedTime()).

For example if your are in the timer behavior (pseudo code):

```
actualSessionLength = now() - getLastAccessedTime();
session.setmaxInactiveInterval(getMaxInactiveInterval() - actualSessionLength);
```

But it might be in the timer behavior too late to shorten the maxInactiveInterval. Maybe you could it do earlier in an `IAjaxCallListener`? And after the AjaxTimerBehavior you would have to set again 30 minutes as the inactiveTimeInterval.

I think it will be hard to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You could invalidate the session yourself with another AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior:

```
add(new AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior(Duration.seconds(300)) {
    @Override
    protected void onTimer(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

        // Get current page
        Page page = target.getPage();

        // invalidate session
        page.getSession().invalidate();

        // Goto LoginPage
        page.setResponsePage(YourLoginPage.class);
     }
});
```